# Wildfly 14 CLI edit default jgroups

Tags: command-line-interface, wildfly

I'm having trouble to change the default channel for jgroups to use a different stack then udp.

I connect with

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c
```

Then i run

```
/subsystem=jgroups/channel=ee:write-attribute(name=stack,value=tcp)
```

And i get error of

```
Failed to get the list of the operation properties:
 "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [
    ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),                                                                                     
    ("channel" => "ee")                                                                                             
]"
```

I have a feeling I´m not connect to the standalone-ha.xml but instead the normal standalone.xml that doesn't contain jgroups. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Worth mentioning is that I'm running on a clean install of Wildfly 14 without any deployments or configurations.

Comment: What's the output of: /profile=ha/subsystem=jgroups:read-resource

Comment: Same exception for that. "No resource definition is registered for address"

Comment: You are not using ha profile. I've downloaded the wildfly14 and found how to. See answer update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the server with ha profile configuration first of all:

```
wildfly-14.0.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml
```

Run Jboss-cli:

```
wildfly-14.0.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=127.0.0.1:9990
```

And then, on jboss-cli:

```
/subsystem=jgroups/channel=ee:write-attribute(name=stack,value=tcp)
```

Comment: I thought that was the case as well but it still throws the same exception